# MVC dropdown select (blank) option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I initially set up my dropdown with submit button which was fine but now I wanted to have it just work without the button (I added onchange). However now I find another difficulty that initially when page is displayed, if I "select" the first option, nothing happens (obviously) so I though to add "please select" option. I found couple of solutions such as writing my custom list of SelectListOptions but this seems like it could be over the top for my case. Could anyone shed some light here and let me know what would be the easiest option here? Sorry if it is simple answer I am really stuck. Here is my code:

**Model**

```
public class SurveyDropdownModel
{
    public SelectList selectSurveys { get; set; }
    public string selectedId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RespondentModel> respondents { get; set; }

    public SurveyDropdownModel(List<SurveyModel> surveys)
    {
        selectSurveys = new SelectList(surveys, "SurveyID", "SurveyTitle");
        respondents = null;
    }
}
public class SurveyModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Survey ID")]
    public int SurveyID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string SurveyTitle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Updated")]
    public DateTime SurveyUpdatedDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        HealthCheckDataLayer.HealthCheckRepository repo = new HealthCheckRepository(connectionString);

        List<SurveyModel> surveyList = repo.ReturnSurveys<SurveyModel>();
        var model = new SurveyDropdownModel(surveyList);
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SurveyDropdownModel model)
    { 
        //not important here 
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model HealthCheckWebApp.Models.SurveyDropdownModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>Select product:</h4>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
        {
        @Html.DropDownList("selectedId", Model.selectSurveys, new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" }) 
        }
    </div>
</div>

<br />
<br />

@if(Model.respondents!=null)
{
@* not relevant here*@
}
```

I guess now that I didn't include how do I pull my list , I am calling a stored procedure from my repository there (It's required to do it with SP).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Html.DropDownListFor`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561(v=vs.118).aspx) is a description.

Usage:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.selectedId, Model.selectSurveys, "Select something", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" )
```